# Approach to create Office Web Add-In along with Ribbon

Tags: excel, add-in, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I am looking to create an Office Web Add-In for MAC (iOS). As of my observations, all add-ins are developed by using task pane. But I am looking an approach to create a Ribbon along with buttons and forms will display based on ribbon button events.

I tried but I didn't get a good result.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for Add-in Commands. You can read about how these work at [Add-in commands for Excel, Word, and PowerPoint](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/add-in-commands).